# How to get contour area in skimage

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-image

I've defined contours in skimage following [documenation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_contours.html?highlight=contour):

```
contours = measure.find_contours(img, 0.8)
```

In OpenCV area could be obtained using:

```
cv2.contourArea(cnt)
```

Does skimage contains something similar (functionality for contour features)?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any similar function in scikit-image, however with some manipulation of the data you can use the function from opencv. You only need to expand the numpy object and convert it to float32 UMat.

```
# Expand numpy dimensions
c = np.expand_dims(countour.astype(np.float32), 1)
# Convert it to UMat object
c = cv2.UMat(c)
area = cv2.contourArea(c)
```